# javascript error listener

Tags: javascript, events, handler

i try using window.attachEvent (or addEventListener) to capture js errors
my callback function gets only one event parameter

my question is: how do i get line number and source file of the error from this event?

the alternative usage window.onerror=callback; works
but an event listener has other benefits thus im giving it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't get line number and source file from an error in IE except via `window.onerror`. In Firefox, `Error` objects have `lineNumber` and `fileName` properties, so if you've caught an error using `try`/`catch` you can use these properties.

Comment: and what about FF? any possiblity?